# php interactive chart dynamic form

Tags: php, charts

I am quite inexperienced with PHP, and I'm looking for the quickest easiest way to create a form that accepts user input and spits out two charts based on the input.

1. Please enter amount: (user enters amount)
2. (user clicks Calculate button)
3. The script should produce two Excel-style charts based on the user input, chart 1 being a bar chart with the input up the Y axis and pre-set percentage values along the X. Chart 2 should be a line chart with similar input and percentages.

The charts should look identical regardless of what the user typed in, it's simply the X values that change. I've had a look around at open source PHP chart libraries, but I'm not sure how I can add the user input functionality.

Can somebody help me?

Comment: How far have you got? Have you encountered a certain problem?

Comment: If you've got any code so far, post it so people can tell how you are implementing your form. Then, I'd recommend having a look at JPGraph - comprehensive and fairly simple to use.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the form, try something like this:

```
<html>
  <body>
    <form action="chart.php" method="post">
      Name: <input type="text" name="amount" />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

And in chart.php:

```
$amount = intval($_POST['amount']);
include('chart_library.php');
show_graph($amount);
```

If you do a Google search for `php chart library`, you can find various libraries that can  show graphs. [JpGraph is an example.](http://jpgraph.net)